# $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx\overset{?}=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to understand what's happened [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1Gap.png). From what I've found online it should be $\sin^{-1}$ not $\cos^{-1}$. But then the proof doesn't work. I'm probably just missing something...

I'm assuming that the equation in the picture isn't of the form suggested in the title or something?

Comment: Start with *let $x=a\cos \theta$.* Now, try.

Comment: Look at the picture I've linked, it's a bit more complicated haha, I'm just guessing that it's of the form in the title...

Comment: There $x=\rho-1/r_0$ and $a=e/r_0$.

Comment: Yeah I can see that, but from what I've seen online it says that it should be arcsin...but http://radio.astro.gla.ac.uk/a1dynamics/ellproof.pdf says it's arccos.

Comment: No, there is no mistake. From @Kf-Sansoo 's answer, he integrated $\frac 1{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$, so if you integrate $-\frac 1{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$, you get $-\sin^{-1}(x/a)+c=-\pi/2+\cos^{-1}(x/a)+c=\cos^{-1}(x/a)+K$ where $K=c+\pi/2$.

Comment: Here I am using the identity $$\arccos x+\arcsin x=\frac \pi 2.$$

Comment: @Nehorai What to?

Comment: @CanofDrink, any title should not contain only MathJax expressions. Be briefly detailed in title. And the title is misleading too. . And have you made out my comments?

Comment: @CanofDrink  see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1645846/203577)

Comment: @SubhadeepDey I think yours is the best answer so far, the identity is what does it I think. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite what SubhadeepDey says in comment

When you do integration and find antiderivative you can only find a unique solution up to addition of constant. For example $\int 2xdx=x^2+C$, it's also true to write $\int 2xdx=x^2+1+C$, $\int 2xdx=x^2-100+C$, $\int 2xdx=x^2+\pi+C$, etc. because $C$ is an arbitrary constant that can "absorb" all the constant terms.

$\arcsin(x)+\arccos(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}\implies \arccos(x)=-\arcsin(x) +\frac{\pi}{2}$. Therefore if it's correct that $\int f(x) dx=-\arcsin(x)+C$ it's also correct that $\int f(x) dx=-\arcsin(x)+\frac{\pi}{2}+C=\arccos(x)+C$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you haven't read any book's solution manual about this problem, we can start again by letting $\theta \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}), x = a\sin \theta\Rightarrow dx = a\cos \theta d\theta\Rightarrow \sqrt{a^2-x^2} = \sqrt{a^2-a^2\sin^2\theta}= a\cos \theta\Rightarrow I = \displaystyle \int 1d\theta= \theta + C = \sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x}{a}\right)+C$

Comment: So what's going on here: http://radio.astro.gla.ac.uk/a1dynamics/ellproof.pdf is there a mistake?